# ¿Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés?

Tags: discusión, traducciones, etiquetas

Me llamó la atención que haya tantas etiquetas en inglés, muchas de ellas con una sola pregunta formulada.

¿Hay algún motivo para seguir manteniéndolas?

¿Convendría tener todas las etiquetas en español o hay algunas que al traducirlas perderían el sentido que le damos en informática? Pienso por ejemplo en la etiqueta **bug**.

Es evidente que algunas etiquetas necesitan traducción. ¿Se puede hacer directamente o es mejor pedir consenso? Hay varias, aquí pueden ver algunas, pero hay más:

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- [editing](/questions/tagged/editing)
- [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki)
- [stack-snippets](/questions/tagged/stack-snippets)
- [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page)
- [english](/questions/tagged/english)
- [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)
- [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)
- [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting)
- [badges](/questions/tagged/badges)
- [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Comment: en cuanto a la nota que agregaste recién... "*no soportasen nada de lo que yo haga aquí*" -No, es justamente lo contrario, creo que no podrías estar más equivocado en cuanto al motivo del cierre. Fui el primero en sugerirlo como duplicado y lo sostengo. **1.** La fecha en la que se publicó ayuda a determinar, pero no es condicionante. **2.** La pregunta sobre la cual se cerró es más completa, se generó en parte gracias a esta pregunta tuya (gran aporte), pero cubre mejor el tema, y fue editada con el resultado por un moderador... Tu edición creo que es superflua y la revertiría.

Comment: @Mariano para serte sincero hay una especie de discurso que me resulta algo patético: _La pregunta sobre la cual se cerró es más completa, se generó en parte gracias a esta pregunta tuya (**gran aporte**), pero cubre mejor el tema..._ No es la primera vez que leo algo **parecido**, como queriendo decir, _lo tuyo es bueno, es admirable, tienes buena intención..._  pero no tiene cabida aquí porque la comunidad ha decidido otra cosa. Resulta que ese discurso y esas actitudes terminan cansando a uno.

Comment: Esta discusión fue llevada a la publicación en Meta: [¿Cuál es el criterio que han seguido para marcar esta pregunta como duplicada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2377/127)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los sitios Meta tienen por defecto una serie de etiquetas, algo así como "etiquetas predefinidas" que se sugieren al ir a etiquetar una pregunta. Es por eso que se han ido creando cosas como [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) y demás.

Estoy de acuerdo en que la mayoría podrían ser renombrados.

También existen casos como *bug* que no creo que haga falta traducir. ¿Qué palabra española usaríamos para hablar de *bug* y que reconozca todo el mundo rápidamente? Ha sido objeto de [preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2772/1674) pero [parece que](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2773/1674) lo más normal es usar la palabra en inglés.

Para todo ello sería útil utilizar la sugerencia de [sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), pero el sistema es largo y poco práctico. Para los casos obvios es mucho más ágil que un moderador lo haga.

Dejaría tal cual:

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) pues trata de un producto de Stack Exchange: [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).
- [stack-snippets](/questions/tagged/stack-snippets)

Son sinónimas de la versión española:

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) de [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n)

Ya limpiadas:

- [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) había una pregunta y la he reetiquetado a [medallas](/questions/tagged/medallas)

Estaría bien traducir:

- [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) → [ediciones](/questions/tagged/ediciones) --> véase [Hagamos [editing] sinónimo de [ediciones]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1743/127)
- [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) → [wiki-de-comunidad](/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad) --> véase [Sinónimo [wiki-de-comunidad] ← [community-wiki] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1774/127)
- [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page) veo que ya existe [perfil](/questions/tagged/perfil), no sé si con exacto uso.
- [english](/questions/tagged/english) → creo que no es ni siquiera necesaria, al igual que [espanol](/questions/tagged/espanol) ---> eliminadas
- [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) → [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) (ya existe) --> [Hacer [burninate-request] sinónimo de [solicitud-de-quemado]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1731/83)
- [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) → ¿formato? --> véase [Sinónimos de [formato] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1769/83) donde se propone unir [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) y [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) en [formato](/questions/tagged/formato)
- [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) → [duplicados-exactos](/questions/tagged/duplicados-exactos) --> véase [Sinónimo [duplicados-exactos] ← [exact-duplicates] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1778/83)

Como casi todas ellas tienen pocas preguntas, sería fácil reetiquetarlas manualmente. Sin embargo, sería mejor crear un sinónimo de etiqueta para que en el futuro se etiqueten correctamente. Además, tengo la sospecha que estas etiquetas en inglés aparecen por defecto en toda página Meta, por lo que si no creamos ese sinónimo, van a reaparecer a medida que sean sugeridas para etiquetar las preguntas.

Comment: Usaría `[ediciones]` ← `[editing]` (no existe, me convence más ese nombre) ... y [[solicitud-de-quemado](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/tags/solicitud-de-quemado/info)] ← `[burninate-request]` (ya está siendo utilizada)

Comment: @Mariano gracias, me gustan las ideas y las incorporo a la respuesta. Por cierto, ¿sabes que los [magic-links](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1059/83) también valen para etiquetas? Esto: [meta-tag:burninate-request] es `[meta-tag:burninate-request]`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Saludos.