# Sinónimos de [formato] en Meta

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, meta

Siguiendo con la propuesta de [¿Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1552/127), estoy proponiendo estos 2 sinónimos en Meta:

- [formato](/questions/tagged/formato) ← [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting)
- [formato](/questions/tagged/formato) ← [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown)

---

Para aprobar los sinónimos: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/formato/synonyms

Comment: Es imposible aprobar los sinónimos: casi nadie tiene suficiente reputación para votar :/

Comment: @fedorqui claro, más aún con una etiqueta recién creada​. La intención era, después de un tiempo prudencial viendo que no hay objeciones, que un moderador vote en ese enlace.

Comment: ¡Bien visto! Como dijiste en otra publicación de estos días: facilitar el proceso para que se materialice el sinónimo con apenas un par de clicks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta semana, el jueves 18 de Mayo del 2017, he aprobado tus dos sugerencias, ahora son sinónimos.

> [formato](/questions/tagged/formato) (etiqueta maestra) - [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) y [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown)