# Sinónimo [wiki-de-comunidad] ← [community-wiki] en Meta

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, meta

Siguiendo con lo comentado en [¿Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1552/127)

#### Estoy proponiendo [wiki-de-comunidad](/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad) ← [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki)

Sinónimo para Meta en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/wiki-de-comunidad/synonyms

- no sugerido aún.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hecho. Se ha creado el sinónimo:

> [wiki-de-comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad) (etiqueta maestra) - [community-wiki](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki)