# Sinónimo [duplicados-exactos] ← [exact-duplicates] en Meta

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, meta

Siguiendo con lo comentado en [¿Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1553/83),

#### Estoy proponiendo [duplicados-exactos](/questions/tagged/duplicados-exactos) ← [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates)

Sinónimo para Meta en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/duplicados-exactos/synonyms

- no sugerido aún.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hecho. Se ha creado el sinónimo:

> [duplicados-exactos](/questions/tagged/duplicados-exactos) (etiqueta maestra) - [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates)

Nota: La etiqueta [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) no tenía ninguna pregunta, por lo que no hubo cambios.

Comment: Cómo te lo curras, ArtEze.